# How to connect to the SQL Server using Internet Connection

Tags: sql-server

Simply this is my Question. I’m using SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition

A)  SQL Server Browser Enable

B)  TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory Enable

C)  Default Port 1433

D)  Server Properties -> Connection -> Allowed remote connections to this server

E)  Port 1433, sqlbrowser.exe, sqlservr.exe Allowed in Firewall

F)  Port forwarding done

1. Computer name\SQL Instance
2. Local IP(given by the router)\SQL Instance
3. Real IP Address\ SQL Instance

I can login with server authentication using 1st and 2nd methods. But I can’t login using the 3rd method
I’ve researched many videos, forums & blogs, but I cannot find any solution.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555613/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-internet-connection

Comment: You may have to tweak your router/[firewall settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Many/most/all(?) routers prevent traffic from public interface to private network behind it. Use the link to understand the ports that need to be opened up. Use your firewall configuration on the router to allow traffic from outside to your local IP of MSSQL.

Comment: why would you want to do this ? poses security risks imho. You should be exposing data from an api